# Sent push notification to Parse, how to receive it in device

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, push-notification, xcode6

I am trying to send and receive push notifications, so when, for example, a certain switch is turned off, another phone with the same app is notified that this has happened by sending an alert message.

The push notifications are being sent successfully to Parse as my account shows all of them sent by my app. However, no messages actually reach the intended device. The list of notifications sent by my app show 0 "Pushes sent" each.

I have sent push notifications from Parse itself to my device and I do receive those correctly, so I don't think it's a problem with the configuration for the notifications.

I followed the Parse guide to configure these but I'll post my code anyways:
AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {


[Parse setApplicationId:@"****My app id****"
              clientKey:@"****My key****"];

UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes
                                                                         categories:nil];
[application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
[application registerForRemoteNotifications];


return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
// Store the deviceToken in the current installation and save it to Parse. 
[PFPush storeDeviceToken:deviceToken];
[PFPush subscribeToChannelInBackground:@""];

PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
[currentInstallation setObject:[PFUser currentUser] forKey:@"owner"];
[currentInstallation saveInBackground];
}


- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
[PFPush handlePush:userInfo];
}
```

Inside my method where my switch changes state:

```
PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
[currentInstallation addUniqueObject:@"HI" forKey:@"try"];
[currentInstallation saveInBackground];

PFPush *push = [[PFPush alloc] init];
[push setChannel:@"HI"];
[push setMessage:@"I am sending a push notification!"];
[push sendPushInBackground];
```

As shown below, Parse receives my push, but has 0 "Pushes sent". There's only 1 subscriber when I send the push from Parse itself, where my iphone does receive it. 
[image]

So basically, how can I get Parse to send that push notification I'm sending from my app in the first place back to my device? I've spent hours researching so please help!!

Comment: You are pushing to a channel named "HI" but you have not registered any devices into this channel, so 0 pushes are sent.

Comment: are you registering installation to "HI" channel? like `currentInstallation.channels = @[ "HI" ];`? and make sure after completing `[currentInstallation saveInBackground];` send the `PFPush`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Paulw11, On first device, you need to register for channel "Hi"

```
 PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];

 [currentInstallation addUniqueObject:@"Hi" forKey:@"channels"];
 [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
```

On second device, where you have change switch part

```
 PFPush *push = [[PFPush alloc] init];
 [push setChannel:@"Hi"];
 [push setMessage:@"I am sending a push notification!"];
 [push sendPushInBackground];
```

Comment: doing same in android but no luck failed to recieve notification http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30303082/failed-to-recieve-notification-sending-on-button-click-using-parse-com-android